# How to make ActiveRecord's association collection methods private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need a way to make association collection methods (particularly the append <<) private. Here's an example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars

  def add_bar (bar)
     # does something extra first
     # but still also use the <<, ultimately
     bars.send(:<<, bar)
  end
end
```

Basically, i do not want any part of the application to be using << by itself, i need it to go through the "add_bar" method. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [private_class_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/private_class_method) (didn't know that myself :)). You can try something along the lines of

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars do
    private_class_method :<<
  end

  def add_bar (bar)
     # does something extra first
     # but still also use the <<, ultimately
     bars.send(:<<, bar)
  end
end
```

Didn't test that, see if it works.

Comment: thanks for the reply! that doesn't seem to work. i am getting a "undefined method `<<' for class `Module'" error. I also tried just "private :<<" and got the same error. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a proxy class that sits in front of the association and make the original association private.  Here's an example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :_bars, :class_name => "Bar"
  private :_weeks

  class BarsProxy

    include ::Enumerable

    def initialize(weeks)
      @weeks = weeks
    end

    def each
      yield @weeks.each
    end

    def create(args = {})
      @weeks.create(args)
    end

    # Plus whatever other methods you want to use on the collection.

  end

  def weeks
    @weeks ||= WeeksProxy.new(_weeks)
  end

end
```